# Route a button to a static IP address in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, database

I'm still a baby in the world of .NET and I've been given a task that I just can't seem to resolve.

I need an application to connect to multiple databases. The databases have static IP addresses.

So basicly when a user clicks on the button database1 then it will go to IP1, and if they click on database2 it routes automatically to IP2.

I have the feeling I've overlooked something probably so simple.

Thanks

Comment: Need to know how you are connecting the databases. You should look into App.Config and ConfigurationManager as there are properties set up specifically to handle multiple connection strings, but it all depends on how you are connecting. If it's hard coded everywhere you will need to swap it out for the "active" string. EDIT: Just noticed this was for web. There are Web.Config files that handle the same way as App.Config

Comment: yeah I'm in the web.config and this is what I have so far.

Comment: <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMade" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

Comment: sorry so messy, new to this site. now i'm stuck as to where I create the classes like RouteHandler and HttpHandler method. Like I said, very new in the .NET world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never done this before but have some idea to achive this. In my project i have references to 2 database. PostgreSQL and Oracle.
In my application i have the several provider classes that implement the database access and use Executor classes for this.
To create the instance of this executors i need to pass the connection string with IP(in local network) of my databases.
The connection string i recive from Web.config file like

```
    //Here is the connection strings with IP, Login, and DBname from web.config You need to configure it dynamicaly
    private string PostgreSQLConnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PostgreSQLConnection"].ConnectionString;
    private string OracleConnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnection"].ConnectionString;

    using (PostgreSQLExecutor executor = new PostgreSQLExecutor(PostgreSQLConnection))
    {
        executor.ExecuteQuery(@"query");
    }

    using (OracleSQLExecutor executor = new OracleSQLExecutor(OracleConnection))
    {
        executor.ExecuteQuery(@"query");
    }
```

There is no problem to pass any string as connection string.
I dont know what database access libary your application use, but im sure it hase the class witch alow you to configure you session like in my example. 
So, i think you just **need to find your database config class** and implement dynamic configuration logic. 
Better would be to create the route with database section like this.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{databaseSection}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { databaseSection = "sectionName1", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
               constraints: new { databaseSection = "sectionName1|sectionName2" }
           );
```

so if application switch the url to site.com/sectionName2/home/index you can retrive the section name and configure you database acces as global behavior.
 For example in global.asax Application_BeginRequest event

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string section = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["databaseSection"].ToString();
    if(section == sectionName2)
    {
        do some stuff to configure your database session 
    }
    else
    {
        default behavior
    }
 }
```

Alternatively you can use the cookie for this. 
Hope it helps. And sorry for my english /:

Comment: Like I said first time, haha, so a complete noob. would this method work on an external IP. with my app, I'll need to click a button which will display the DB in the same window. Or at least the tables, or views, depending on the user permissions. The DB though, should be accessible from anywhere, internet, vpn, local, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

1) Have 2 connections in web.config file.
2) On button one click event refer to first IP and on the other button click connect you another IP.

Comment: ok seems easy enough but then I still have to do the system.web.routing thing first right?

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a complete noob, could you maybe give me a bit more info? I've never done this before. looking back now maybe I was a little unclear in my question. when I enter my app there needs to be a button(that's done of course) then when I click it a list appears on the page and then I should be able to see a table, or view, depending on my user profile. The DB is on a static IP and connected through internet, so not local.